# Laravel: mobile and web app

Tags: angularjs, api, laravel, controller

I am trying to create a web application that can be used either through a browser or natively through a mobile device. I am not sure what are the best practices behind doing so. I am considering building an api backend using laravel that will respond with json encoded data. But if i decided to do so, I am sort of confused about how I will be sending out the HTML template to the browser.

Should I implement 2 different controllers (one for regular web access and one for mobile device access)? Is this a good time to be using something like AngularJs ( I have never used it)?If so, where does it go in my Laravel application?

If you believe that there is a better to achieve my wants outside of my recommendations, by all means express your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a single controller `API` and using `AngularJS` is highly preferable. Otherwise, you'll end up doing the templating thing twice, first for the web and then for the mobile app.

If this be my case, I'd prefer `AngularJS2` as a frontend for my Web-App and then use [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) or [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) or [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to convert the same frontend to a mobile app. Although choosing any of those mobile-app frameworks shall solely depend upon the needs and features the app requires.

However, I link a basic tutorial for Laravel 5 - AngularJS. You should [check it out](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial), to give you a view

Comment: I have gone with this option. Thank you for your input. I have starteed learning angular. It indeed solves this problem. If anyone is interested, my backend infrastructure is currently limited to apis while my font end just retrieves the api data in Json form. Happy Coding everyone

Answer (score 1):

The best choice is to do the webapp and the mobile app with the same API. You can use the great [package Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) to handle the API part in Laravel, it's really easy to use and helps a lot.

And to stay within the (almost) same technologies for the front-end, use [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) for the webapp and [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) (which uses Angular) for the mobile app. Everything is pure front-end technology (javascript, html, css).